# Is there a accepted concept name that covers both associative and unordered associative containers?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++20

Let's assume I have a function that accepts a container and uses the .insert or .find on it, meaning it is either unordered associative container, or associative container.

Is there a common C++ name for this kind of containers?

Comment: *associative container*?

Comment: yeah, but I do not feel associative container is superset of unordered associative container

Comment: Why not?  An unordered associative container is still an associative container.

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_containers note that wiki article may be bad

Comment: @NathanOliver "An AssociativeContainer is an **ordered** Container ..." https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AssociativeContainer

Comment: Just to state what I think is obvious: associative containers are either ordered associative containers (such as `std::map`) or unordered associative containers. (`std::unordered_map`). We might not have a `std::ordered_map` but that's a historical naming accident.

Comment: @Slava Hun.  That seems kind of limiting.  I would think associative container would be the main group and then you would have ordered or unordered as the sub groups.

Comment: Looks like there is no such named concept now https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req it may come when concepts will be implemented

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl could you please provide an example where that would matter? Is it a matter of performance? because otherwise a find is a find and an insert is an insert ...

Comment: @OrenIshShalom it is for constraining function template parameter, to give better errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, none of the proposals for adding concepts to the standard library conceptualize the containers themselves. They conceptualize iterators and ranges, along with algorithm versions that use those concepts. And the containers can use concepts for various things.

But there aren't concepts for detecting the capabilities of a container beyond their range capacities.